# Equivalent of automapper in a silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, reference, automapper

I have a Silverlight 5 project. I want to install automapper in it with nugget or by adding reference to his ddl. But he told me that only packages with Silverlight runtime can be added to a Silverlight.

Is there an alternative to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using [Emit Mapper](http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/) in both Silverlight and server-side code. No major issues so far.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard very good things about [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/releases/view/60311) and they have a Silverlight library.

Here is a quick example:

```
    public class Source
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Target
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    var s = new Source { Id = 3, Name = "Bill" };
    var t = new Target();

    t.InjectFrom(s);
```

**Note**: [There will be no Silverlight 5 support for automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/180):

> I just ditched all of Silverlight. It was just too annoying to
>   support, to be honest. Feel free to fork the code from before me
>   ditching it, but it was just too much work for me.

Comment: There is no support for future versions of Silverlight. There is still Silverlight support, however.

Comment: I noticed the file is blocked because of downloading from web. Now it works for SL4 http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/124367-open-file-security-warning-unblock-file.html